# Найти количество непрерывно повторяющихся значений в столбце

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть исходная таблица со столбцами **A B C** :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо с помощью SQL запроса вычислить столбец **D**, в котором отразить количество идущих подряд значений поля **C** равных 50, сохранив исходную сортировку.

Comment: вы бы сам запрос привели в котором синтаксис надо переделать

Comment: @Pithein отличная правка )

Comment: @Serg не надо заниматься вандализмом

Answer (score 1):

```
select A,B,C,
       row_number() over(partition by A,X order by B)-1 D
  from (
   select A,B,C,count(case when C!=50 then 1 end) over(partition by A order by B) X
     from Tab
  ) Q
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12254/2)

Answer (score 0):

для оракл использовать лучше функцию sign

```
SELECT SIGN(45 - 50), SIGN(50-50), SIGN(55-50)  FROM dual;
```

похоже для msssql эта же функция работает https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql

корректирую:
все равно  можно использовать :

```
case when book_num = 50 then 50 else 0 end
```

дальше конечно интересно можно использовать :

```
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY case when book_num = 50 then 50 else 0 end 
/*но тут нужно еще поле по которому группировать*/)
```

У меня получилось без вложенного запроса, проверьте http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12254/9

```
SELECT T.A, T.B, T.C,
       CASE WHEN T.C = 50 THEN
          RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY T.A, T.C ORDER BY T.B)
         ELSE 0 END AS D
  FROM TAB AS T
 ORDER BY T.A, T.B
```

Comment: почему вы подумали что нужна sign, в вопросе не вижу требований отрицательных значений

Comment: а точно... сейчас переделаю

Comment: `when sign( book_num - 50 ) = 0` это конечно круто, но зачем же так усложнять, это же равноценно `when book_num=50`. sign в этой задаче ну как бы совершенно ни для чего не нужна

Comment: ) ну в общем да

Comment: и `PARTITION BY case when book_num = 50 then 50 else 0 end` соберет все 50 в одно окно. судя по тому, что на картинке требуется разбивать по порядку выдачи, правда ТС не указал порядок.

Comment: @Serg Но порядок имеет значение. если на вашей картинке все записи 50 собрать вместе то и нумерация у них будет одна общая на всех. И опишите вашу задачу подробнее и главное, приведите тот запрос, который как вы пишите, надо исправить. Невозможно исправить то, чего нет.

Comment: добавил вариант на основе другого ответа.