# Как посчитать количество элементов в однотипных группах на PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос, который возвращает поля date (первое число очередного месяца), contragent_id, debet - сумма списаний с контрагента за все время на текущий месяц, credit - сумма начислений от контрагента за все время на текущий месяц. Также выводится столбец dolg со значением 1/0: 1 - суммарные начисления от контрагента меньше, чем суммарные списания, 0 - начисления больше или равны.
Необходимо посчитать количество непрерывных месяцев подряд, в которых у контрагента столбец dolg возвращает единицу

Пример, как это должно выглядеть (count - высчитанный столбец с нужным мне результатом):

---

```
┌─────────────┬───────────────┬───────┬────────┬──────┬───────┐
│ date        │ contragent_id │ debet │ credit │ dolg │ count │
├─────────────┼───────────────┼───────┼────────┼──────┼───────┤
│ 01.02.2019  │ 1             │ 100   │ 50     │ 1    │ 1     │
│ 01.03.2019  │ 1             │ 150   │ 50     │ 1    │ 2     │
│ 01.04.2019  │ 1             │ 200   │ 200    │ 0    │ 0     │
│ 01.05.2019  │ 1             │ 250   │ 200    │ 1    │ 1     │
│ 01.06.2019  │ 1             │ 300   │ 270    │ 1    │ 2     │
│ 01.07.2019  │ 1             │ 350   │ 270    │ 1    │ 3     │
│ 01.08.2019  │ 1             │ 400   │ 450    │ 0    │ 0     │
└─────────────┴───────────────┴───────┴────────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Найти количество непрерывно повторяющихся значений в столбце](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704979/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b5)

Comment: Рановато вы на дубль согласились. Ответы в том вопросе на этот не особо подходят. А я как раз более подходящее решение сделал ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6261e/1